# How to derive the meaning of error produced by make?

Tags: makefile

Having this simple makefile rule:

```
exe:
   for i in *; do [ -x "$$i" ] && echo "$$i"; done
```

Will output:

```
for i in *; do [ -x "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
executablefile
make: *** [makefile:6: exe] Error 1
```

So it does, what I want, but even then, error with no other message. But not only for this particular example (which I still do not get), I would like to know, how to get some more info from bugs in makefile (is there a makefile debugger?). From makefile manual the `***` is for fatal error, which ends compilation, but yet it outputs the executablefile (so it did compiled to that point). Apart from fatal error, `-` warnings give more info, so why do not do fatal errors as well?

1. explanation of this example
2. some advices how to debug makefile scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error from make, that's why there's no other information.

Make runs a shell and gives the shell your recipe to invoke.  If the shell exits with success (exit code 0) then make assumes that the command it ran worked.  If the shell exits with failure (any exit code other than 0), then make assumes the command it ran failed.  Make doesn't know *why* it failed, make assumes that whatever command failed will have printed some information about why.  All make knows is the exit code, so that's all make can tell you:

```
make: *** [makefile:6: exe] Error 1
```

This means that make ran the recipe for target `exe` at `makefile` line number 6, and that command exited with an error code 1 (which is not 0, hence a failure).

Why did this happen?  Let's look at your shell script:

```
for i in *; do [ -x "$$i" ] && echo "$$i"; done
```

Let's suppose the last file matching `*` (so the last time we go through the loop) the file is not executable.  That means the test of the last file `[ -x "$$i" ]` will fail.  Since that's the last command that the shell runs before it exits, that will be the exit code of the shell, and you have a failure.

You need to be sure that the shell exits with success.  One way to do that is ensure the last command the shell runs is always success; maybe something like this:

```
for i in *; do [ -x "$$i" ] && echo "$$i"; done; true
```